# Python with GDAL and PostGIS as a replacement of ArcGIS

Tags: python, postgis, arcgis-desktop, gdal, software-recommendations

Few times ago, I worked with daily land surface temperature satellite images of an area with the size of Alaska.

I had to process around one thousand images. I downloaded them, mosaiced, projected, clipped to shapefile boundaries, extracted means out of the clipped rasters, and plotted the means on a time-temperature graph. The time-temperature graph was the final output.
I did all these in ArcGIS, and even though I created an ArcPy script which helped automating a part of the work, it was still painstaking.

Now I want to build a program that does the same thing, but 100% automatically. I merely want to input to the program the coordinates of the corners in order to define the area of interest and get the final output generated which is the time-temperature graph.

Do you think this is possible using Python with the GDAL library and PostGIS as a raster data store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - is the short answer.  I think you will need [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) as part of your Python solution.  Have a look at the scipy.ndimage module when it comes to calculating means (are these zonal means?)  as this will be a lot quicker than doing it with just NumPy.  Also, by using the Python [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module, you will get a significant speed gain.  However, keep the number of subprocesses down as raster processing can be processor-intensive and you could end up slowing the machine down rather than speeding it up.  I suggest 1 less process than cores on your machine.

Comment: What about the bit of downloading the data? In general, what information would you need to know?

Comment: @dchaboya : I am not sure what you mean. The ftplib library would do the downloading task I think.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I was refering to.  Wasn't sure which module\library was being used to do that part of the task.